# Swift 5 – How to use base emoji in case statement that may have skin-tone emoji as input?

Tags: swift, emoji

The input to my switch may or may not be an emoji with skin tone.

Do I have to test for all six variations for each emoji that can have a skin tone or **is there a simple one-liner way to strip out the base emoji from the emoji modifier?**

Here is my failing code:

```
switch blah {
    case "✅":
        daIcon = self.iconComplete!
    case "":
        daIcon = self.iconConfirmed!
    case "":
        daIcon = self.iconMessageLeft!
    case "":
        daIcon = self.iconLookingForDocs!
    case "☎️":
        daIcon = self.iconVoiceMailLeft!
    case "❌":
        daIcon = self.iconPostponed!
    default:
         daIcon = self.iconRedQuestion!
}
```

Edit:

I am new to all of this from a programming perspective. I knew that emoji took more than "a" byte and that zero-width whatchamacallits existed, but it was not unit the above switch statement failed that I needed to learn more. LOL

In this particular use case, I am just using a series of emojis to indicate various status states. Therefore, I do not anticipate needing any of the more complicated combinations (e.g. ‍‍).

The full list is: ✅, ⭕, , , , ☎️, ❓, ‼️, ⁉️, , , , ⭕️, ❌, ⚠️, , , , ,  and of course, .

Comment: Will the cases always be base emojis? Or will some of the cases be "I want to match this variation exactly" and some of the cases be "I want to match any variation of this base emoji".

Comment: "Base emoji…" Yeah, that's a very interesting question in the general case. What's the "base emoji" for ‍‍ (MAN+FITZPATRICK_TYPE_5+ZWJ+HANDSHAKE+ZWJ+MAN+FITZPATRICK_TYPE_3). Is it MAN (first element)? Or MAN+ZWJ+HANDSHAKE+ZWJ+MAN (removing skin-tone modifiers)? Or ADULT+ZWJ+HANDSHAKE+ZWJ+ADULT (also replacing w/ neutral gender). Honestly, the best answer is "-ZWJ+HANDSHAKE+ZWJ-" which is the "stem" of all the variants. But the best single character would be HANDSHAKE. That's an elaborate algorithm. But for special cases for a short list, I think Sweeper is definitely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this is to first check if the string is a single `Character`, then get the first unicode scalar. That will be the unmodified base emoji.

You can write your own `~=` operator for `String`, s

```
// or if...else if you are doing other stuff after the switch
guard blah.count == 1 else {
    daIcon = self.iconRedQuestion!
    return
}
switch blah.unicodeScalars.first {
case "✅":
    daIcon = self.iconComplete!
case "":
    daIcon = self.iconConfirmed!
case "":
    daIcon = self.iconMessageLeft!
case "":
    daIcon = self.iconLookingForDocs!
case "☎":
    daIcon = self.iconVoiceMailLeft!
case "❌":
    daIcon = self.iconPostponed!
default:
    daIcon = self.iconRedQuestion!
}
```

Note that the ☎️ emoji is actually ☎ (U+260E BLACK TELEPHONE) plus a variation selector. You should use only U+260E in the cases.

You can also use [Smile](https://github.com/onmyway133/Smile), specifically the `unmodify(emoji:)` and `isSingleEmoji` functions, which are implemented similarly as above.

Note that this approach picks out the first emoji in a ZWJ sequence, which may or may not be expected.